# Angular5: template to choose

Tags: angular

I have to create a  admin-panel application with Angular (last version), which is for your experiences the most stable graphic framework solution for some crud operations?: Material design, ng-bootstrap, etc..

Buy an angular template already developed is a good idea? or I could just waste time to fix conflicts?

Thanks in advance.
Andrea

Comment: you can use ng-bootstrap or ng-semantic

Comment: take a look to [Nebular](https://github.com/akveo/nebular) its a good template